# How do I return a promise before protractor expect runs?

Tags: javascript, protractor

```
Person.prototype.checkAssignmentIncomplete = Person.chain(function (data) {
var self = this;

var assignmentPane = self.browser.element(by.id(data.testId + '#' + data.deadline));
expect(assignmentPane.isPresent()).toBe(true);

assignmentPane.click();
self.browser.waitForAngular();

var foundName = false;
var promises = [];
element.all(by.binding('member.user.fullname')).each(function (nameColumn) {
    var row = nameColumn.element(by.xpath('..'));
    var promise = nameColumn.getText().then(function (name) {
        foundName = foundName || data.name === name;
        if (foundName) {
            var reviewButton = row.element(by.className('icon'));
            expect(reviewButton.isPresent()).toBe(false);
        }
    });
    promises.push(promise);
});

q.all(promises).then(function () {
    expect(foundName).toBe(true);
});

});
```

I'm having problems with my automated testing in Protractor, it seems to be think that foundName is false and I know for a fact that when this runs it is indeed true. My conclusion is that the expect function is being run before the promise has finished.

I was wondering how I can make sure the promise has finished before I check the foundName in the expect function?

Comment: To resolve the promises you need to explicitly run the `$scope.$digest()`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but we can't use scope in protractors tests.

Comment: `all`/`each` are asynchronous, right?

Comment: Well your spec looks like a mess, I'd suggest using `it` blocks to help the control flow.  But are you looking for something like this? `var deferred = protractor.promise.defer();
return deferred.promise;`

Comment: Or try modifying that statement?  I use Protractor on non-angular so `q` isn't available to me - but could you do:  `promises.each(function (foundName) {
    expect(foundName).toBe(true);
});` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var self = this;

var assignmentPane = self.browser.element(by.id(data.testId + '#' + data.deadline));
expect(assignmentPane.isPresent()).toBe(true);

assignmentPane.click();
self.browser.waitForAngular();

var foundName = false;
element.all(by.binding('member.user.fullname')).each(function (nameColumn) {
    var row = nameColumn.element(by.xpath('..'));
    nameColumn.getText().then(function (name) {
        foundName = foundName || data.name === name;
        if (foundName) {
            var reviewButton = row.element(by.className('icon'));
            expect(reviewButton.isPresent()).toBe(false);
        }
    });
}).then(function () {
    expect(foundName).toBe(true);
});
```

This isn't really an ideal solution but adding the promise after the each function seemed to fix the problem that I was having.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use protractor.promise.all(promises) function to have callback when array of promises are resolved - 
https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=promise.all

q lib is might not work here